# Codeigniter Error box showing when not required and success message implementation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unsure what would be the best way to implement a success message into a different div.

I also am getting the error div loaded into my view when the page is loaded why?  I want it to show if only if there as an error.

If there is no error how could I change the div and include a success message?

**View:**

```
<div class="alert alert-error">
    <?php echo validation_errors();?>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
            {
                $userData = array(
                    'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
                    'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
                    'password' => sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
                );  

                $this->db->escape($userData);
                $this->user_model->addUser($userData);
            }

            $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
            $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
            $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
            $this->load->view('_assets/footer');
    }
```

**Update:**

```
<?php 

    $errorMessage = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>'); 
    $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank You</strong> Your User Has Been Added';   
        if($errorMessage)
        {
            echo $errorMessage;
        }else{
            echo $successMessage;
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by the following:

```
    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
        {
            $userData = array(
                'fName' => $this->input->post('userFirstName', TRUE),
                'lName' => $this->input->post('userLastName', TRUE),
                'email' => $this->input->post('userEmail', TRUE),
                'password' => sha1($this->input->post('userPassword', TRUE))
            );  

            $this->db->escape($userData);
            $this->user_model->addUser($userData);

            $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
            $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
            $data['message'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Thank You</strong> Your User Has Been Added';
            $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
            $this->load->view('_assets/footer');

        }elseif($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $data['contentMangement'] = $this->options_model->systemOptions();
            $data['pageTitle'] = 'Add User';
            $data['message'] = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>'); 
            $this->load->view('_assets/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('addUser', $data);
            $this->load->view('_assets/footer');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php 
$errorMsg = validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
if ($errorMsg){
    echo $errorMsg;
}
else{
    echo 'Success message';
}
?>
```

[errordelimiters](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#errordelimiters)

Comment: Thanks,  How would I go about setting a success message and changing the div?

Comment: Thanks @Musa,  I hace updated my question it is now showing the success message permanently why?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie As per your request if there is no error message then a success message will be shown, If you don't want to show any message you'll have to state the condition in which this will occur.

Comment: I am trying to get it so that if there is no error display success but this should only load if the data was submitted and correct.